Is there a way to turn off or disable sending MMS messages but not receiving them?
I would like to disable or turn off the sending of MMS messages. In the absence of RCS on the receiver's phone, Google Messages sometimes auto-converts an SMS to MMS when sending. I have looked up about disabling this feature, but there is no way that I have found to do so (although I would be happy to hear if anyone knows otherwise).
Therefore, I wonder if it is possible to turn off or disable MMS sending altogether without affecting receiving MMS messages. While various answers suggest it is possible to disable MMS completely, I haven't seen anything about disabling only sending MMS. Is there a setting or workaround to do so?
